# SQL Server Increase script performance by finding another way of doing the same type of join

Tags: sql, performance, sql-server-2012

I have a script which for a given time period returns only the rows in question and duplicates any row which took over 60 seconds to send. This is achieved by doing the following join:

```
FROM Table t
INNER JOIN CTE_DayHourMinutes dhm ON
Calculate_Date >= t.[Start Date]
AND 
dhm.Calculate_Date <= t.[End Date]
```

For each record in table t where it matches with the YYYY-MM-DD HH-MM-SS of the calculated date it joins together. The only issue with this is it takes 10 or so minutes to return 100 records. Eventually, the script shall be used internally on a system which could potentially have thousands if not millions of rows as we shall be looking to pull through three months’ worth of data.

I should also mention, I have tested the rest of the script and every works fine and with no performance issues when runnign the necessary CTE's and other sections. The only issue is the way I am trying to do the above join and the number of rows it has to check, which at present takes far too long.

As such I am at a loss as to how the above could be achieved in a similar way but improve the performance of the script.

'

```
DECLARE
    @startDate DateTime 
,   @currentDate DateTime

/* Demo System */    SET @currentDate = '2014-04-26'

SET @startDate = DATEADD(day, -10 , @CurrentDate)

-- Create a list of Days (depending on the month in question)
-------------------------------------------------------------
; WITH CTE_dayList as
(
SELECT @startDate as cal_day
union all
SELECT DATEADD(DAY , 1, d1var.cal_day) as cal_day FROM CTE_daylist d1var 
WHERE  DATEADD(DAY , 1, d1var.cal_day) <= @currentDate 
)

-- Create a list of hours 0 - 23 (24 hours)
-------------------------------------------
, CTE_hourList as
(
SELECT 0  as cal_hour
union all
SELECT h1var.cal_hour + 1 as cal_hour FROM CTE_hourList h1var 
WHERE h1var.cal_hour + 1 <= 23 
)

-- Create a list of minutes 0 - 59 (1 hour)
-------------------------------------------
, CTE_minuteList as
(
SELECT 0  as cal_minute
union all
SELECT m1var.cal_minute + 1 as cal_minute FROM CTE_minuteList m1var 
WHERE m1var.cal_minute + 1 <= 59 
)

-- Create a day , hour and minnute -- cross join the hour and minute onto each day between the two dates.

, CTE_DayHourMinutes as
(
SELECT
    -- cast the cal_day (date) with the hours and minute, to create a date and time.
    CAST(CAST(cal_day AS VARCHAR) + CAST(CAST(cal_hour as VARCHAR) + ':' + CAST(cal_minute AS VARCHAR) AS DATETIME) AS DATETIME) AS Calculate_Date
FROM CTE_dayList  
CROSS JOIN
(SELECT cal_hour , cal_minute FROM CTE_hourList CROSS JOIN CTE_minuteList) DHMList)

-- create transmission end date and time ( required for the join in the main select statement )


, CTE_Text RF as
(
SELECT
        H.ObjectGuid AS Transmission_ID
    ,   CAST(H.[TRDateTime] AS DateTime) AS [Transmission Start Date]
    ,   CAST(DATEADD(second, HT.ElapsedTime, H.TRDateTime) AS DateTime) AS [Transmission End Date]
    ,   HT.[ElapsedTime] AS [Time taken to send]
    ,   HT.GoodPageCount AS Pages
    ,   HT.[ChannelUsed]
FROM [dbo].History AS H (NOLOCK)
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].HistoryTRX AS HT (NOLOCK) ON H.handle = HT.handle

)

SELECT 

        Calculate_Date AS [Full Calculated Date]
    ,   CAST(Calculate_Date AS DATE) AS Calculated_Date
    ,   CAST(DATEPART(YYYY , dhm.Calculate_Date) AS VARCHAR ) + '-' + RIGHT('0' + CAST(DATEPART(Month , dhm.Calculate_Date) AS VARCHAR) , 2) AS [Calculated Year-Month]
    ,   CAST(DATEPART(YYYY , dhm.Calculate_Date) AS VARCHAR ) + '-' + RIGHT('0' + CAST(DATEPART(Week , dhm.Calculate_Date) AS VARCHAR) , 2)  AS [Calculated Year-Week]
    ,   CAST(DATEPART(YYYY , dhm.Calculate_Date) AS VARCHAR ) + '-' + RIGHT('0' + CAST(DATEPART(DAY , dhm.Calculate_Date) AS VARCHAR) , 2)   AS [Calculated Year-Day]

    ,   DATEPART(YYYY, dhm.Calculate_Date)                                  AS [Calculated Year]
    ,   RIGHT('0' + CAST(DATEPART(MM, dhm.Calculate_Date) AS VARCHAR) ,2)   AS [Calculated Month]
    ,   DATEPART(Week, dhm.Calculate_Date)                                  AS [Calculated Week]
    ,   DATEPART(DAY, dhm.Calculate_Date)                                   AS [Calculated Day]

   ,    RF.Transmission_ID
   ,    RF.[Transmission Start Date]
   ,    RF.[Transmission End Date]
   ,    RIGHT('0' + CAST(DATEPART(HOUR , RF.[Transmission Start Date]) AS VARCHAR) ,2) + ':' + RIGHT('0' + CAST(DATEPART(Minute , RF.[Transmission Start Date]) AS VARCHAR) ,2) AS [Transmission Start Time]
   ,    RIGHT('0' + CAST(DATEPART(HOUR , RF.[Transmission End Date]) AS VARCHAR) ,2) + ':' + RIGHT('0' + CAST(DATEPART(Minute , RF.[Transmission End Date]) AS VARCHAR) ,2) AS [Transmission End Time]
   ,    RF.[Time taken to send]
   ,    RF.Pages
   ,    RF.[ChannelUsed]

FROM CTE_Text RF
INNER JOIN CTE_DayHourMinutes dhm ON

        -- Join where the calculate_date is between the start and end date of the transmission date.           
           dhm.Calculate_Date >= RF.[Transmission Start Date]
           AND 
           dhm.Calculate_Date <= RF.[Transmission End Date]
```

Comment: Too broad. Show more of your code (such as your CTE), and some benchmarks / profiling data

Comment: ... And relevant table structures including indexes and execution plan

Comment: Where is the logic that deals with 60sec condition?

Comment: Added the code a requested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest these changes below based on the code you put above and some guesses on what is missing such as data type and table model, existing index or pk, etc. Update/Info would be nice.

- I supposed that data type are as follow

  - create table History(

    ```
    ObjectGuid uniqueidentifier
    TRDateTime datetime
    handle bigint
    ```
  - HistoryTRX

    ```
    ElapsedTime int
    GoodPageCount int
    ChannelUsed int
    handle bigint
    ```
- Altough it won't improve the whole query, CTE_DayHourMinutes is faster and shorter this way:

  ```
  ; with CTE_DayHourMinutes(Calculate_Date) as (
  select @startDate
  union all 
  select DATEADD(MINUTE, 1, Calculate_Date) from CTE_DayHourMinutes 
  where Calculate_Date<DATEADD(MINUTE, 60*24-1, @currentDate)
  )
  Select Calculate_Date From  CTE_DayHourMinutes
  Option (MaxRecursion 0)
  ```
- CTE_Text RF table scan

  You should first join [dbo].History with CTE_DayHourMinutes as early as possible and try to reduce the scope of this CTE and history table. Right now you are probably scanning the whole History table + all or part of HistoryTRX
- LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].HistoryTRX

  when there is no match between the 2 tables, HT.ElapsedTime is null. Therefore [Transmission End Date] is null and  dhm.Calculate_Date >= RF.[Transmission Start Date] AND dhm.Calculate_Date <= RF.[Transmission End Date] do not match. You probably need a inner join and/or need to review/rethink what you want to achieve.
- Remove cast and function as much as possible

  It looks like most of them are not needed. They also prevent proper usage of the indexes.
- Review your indexes

  Are they properly set and usefull?